# Facing some issues while installing @vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I've got this message during the installation:

> npm ERR! code EEXIST
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\32493\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
> npm ERR! dest C:\Users\32493\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue
> npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\32493\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\bin\vue.js' -> 'C:\Users\32493\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue'
> npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\32493\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue
> npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
> npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\32493\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-13T13_07_09_420Z-debug.log